# Approximating an exponent of non-commutative matrices as a product of exponents

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, matrix-exponential, quantum-computation, quantum-information

The book Quantum Computation and Quantum Information chapter 4.7.1
presents the following equation.
\begin{equation}
e^{i(A+B)\Delta t} = e^{i A \Delta t}e^{i B \Delta t} + O(\Delta t^2)
\end{equation}
with non-commuting Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$.

I would like to prove the equation above. So far my attempt is to approximate all three exponents
\begin{align}
\tag{1} e^{i(A+B)\Delta t} &= I + i(A + B) \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2),\\
\tag{2} e^{i A \Delta t} &=  I + i A \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2),\\
\tag{3}e^{i B \Delta t} &=  I + i B \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2),\\
\end{align}
Then multiplying (2) and (3)
\begin{align}
e^{i A \Delta t}e^{i B \Delta t} &= (I + i A \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2))(I + i B \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2))\\
\tag{4}&=I + i(A + B) \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2).
\end{align}
Then (4) looks exactly like (1) so I naively conclude
\begin{equation}
e^{i(A+B)\Delta t} = I + i(A + B) \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) =  e^{i A \Delta t}e^{i B \Delta t} + O(\Delta t^2).
\end{equation}
The last step feels a bit strange but I don't know where the problem is. Could anyone point out a mistake or suggest a proper way of doing it?

Comment: Subtract $(4)$ from $(1)$ and you get the last equality.